# Calculating the minimum translation to seperate two lines

Tags: c++, geometry, computational-geometry

Given two intersecting  line segments(AB and CD) in R2 find the translation with the smallest magnitude to apply to CD so that it is no longer intersecting AB.

What I've tried. I calculate the distance from each point on each line to the opposite line. Then I pick the smallest of the 4 values and apply that to the perpendicular of the line. However, the translation I calculate is often in the wrong direction. How do I fix this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

class Vector2
{
public:
    double x;
    double y;

    Vector2() : x(x), y(y) {}
    Vector2(double x, double y) : x(x), y(y) {}

    Vector2 operator*(double val) { return Vector2(x*val, y*val);}
    Vector2 operator/(double val) { return Vector2(x/val, y/val);}
    Vector2 operator+(Vector2 &v) { return Vector2(x+v.x, y+v.y);}
    Vector2 operator-(Vector2 &v) { return Vector2(x-v.x, y-v.y);}

     Vector2 Perpendicular()  { return Vector2(y, -x); }
     double Dot( Vector2 &v)  {return (x * v.x) + (y * v.y); }
     double Magnitude()  { return std::sqrt(Dot(*this)); }
     Vector2 Normal()  { return *this / Magnitude(); }
     double GetDistance( Vector2 &v)  {  Vector2 d = *this - v; return d.Magnitude(); }
};


class Line
{
public:
    Line() : a(Vector2()), b(Vector2()) {}
    Line( Vector2 a,  Vector2 b) : a(a), b(b) {};
     double DistanceFromPoint( Vector2 &p) ;
     Vector2 GetTranslation( Line &l) ;
     Vector2& GetPoint(unsigned i) {if (i==0) return a; else return b;}
     double GetLength()  { return GetPoint(0).GetDistance(GetPoint(1)); }

    Vector2 a;
    Vector2 b;
};

 double Line::DistanceFromPoint( Vector2 &p) 
{
     double l2 = GetLength() * GetLength();
     Vector2 pv = p - GetPoint(0);
     Vector2 wv = GetPoint(1) - GetPoint(0);
     double t = std::max(0.d, std::min(1.d, pv.Dot(wv) / l2));
     Vector2 projection = (wv * t) + GetPoint(0);

    return p.GetDistance(projection);
}

 Vector2 Line::GetTranslation( Line &l) 
{
    // Calculate Distances from each point to rthe opposite line
    std::vector<double> dist(4);
    dist[0] = DistanceFromPoint(l.GetPoint(0));
    dist[1] = DistanceFromPoint(l.GetPoint(1));
    dist[2] = l.DistanceFromPoint(GetPoint(0));
    dist[3] = l.DistanceFromPoint(GetPoint(1));

    //Get the smallest distance
    auto it = std::min_element(std::begin(dist), std::end(dist));
    double min = *it;
    unsigned pos = std::distance(std::begin(dist), it);

    // Get the normalized perpendicular of line
    Vector2 axis;
    if (pos == 2 || pos == 3)
        axis = (GetPoint(1) - GetPoint(0)).Perpendicular().Normal();
    else
        axis = (l.GetPoint(1) - l.GetPoint(0)).Perpendicular().Normal();

    std::cout << "min: " << min << std::endl;
    std::cout << "axis: (" << axis.x << "," << axis.y << ")" << std::endl;

    //Apply that min to the perpendicular
    return axis * min;
}

int main()
{
    Line A;
    Line B;

    Vector2 t;

    std::cout << "Left" << std::endl;
    A = Line(Vector2(0, 4), Vector2(8, 4));
    B = Line(Vector2(2, 0), Vector2(2, 6));
    t = A.GetTranslation(B);
    std::cout << "Expected: (-2, 0)" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Got: (" << t.x << "," << t.y << ")" << std::endl << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Right" << std::endl;
    B = Line(Vector2(6, 0), Vector2(6, 6));
    t = A.GetTranslation(B);
    std::cout << "Expected: (2, 0)" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "translation: (" << t.x << "," << t.y << ")" << std::endl << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Top" << std::endl;
    B = Line(Vector2(4, 0), Vector2(4, 6));
    t = A.GetTranslation(B);
    std::cout << "Expected: (0, -2)" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "translation: (" << t.x << "," << t.y << ")" << std::endl << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Bottom" << std::endl;
    B = Line(Vector2(4, 6), Vector2(4, 8));
    t = A.GetTranslation(B);
    std::cout << "Expected: (0, -2)" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "translation: (" << t.x << "," << t.y << ")" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea will work. You only need to have a signed distance function like @Tommy mentioned. Also, note that you will have to get the *right* perpendicular direction as well, depending on your sign conventions in the distance function.

[Here is a demo](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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)

Comment: your demo seems to move a different line depending on the distance. I would like to always move CD

Comment: That's a minor modification. In the demo (I have updated it), you can replace line 53 with `var pointLinePairs = [[p1, l2], [p2, l2]];`.  That will always move the line `l2`.

Comment: Yup, I was quick to suggest (wrongly) the edit above. It should be fixed now.

Comment: what did you do to fix it?

Comment: I don't really know much js so I'm having trouble following your code.

Comment: Line 83: 
```
if (minLine != lineToDisplace) {
    vecD = -vecD
}
```
Considering line segments AB and CD from your example, first, we run through a loop to find the end point with minimum distance from the lines. We have to get the distance and the corresponding line (call it `dist` and `baseLine`). If the baseline is the one you are trying to move (CD in your example), we just translate CD w.r.t. the vector `<unit normal of baseLine * dist>`. On the other hand, if baseline is equal to AB, then we have to reverse the direction to translate. That's the change made in the demo.

Answer (score -1):

You've got the right approach. From reasoning about the Minkowski sum, the shortest vector of separation will be perpendicular to one of the lines and will be just long enough to push one of the endpoints to the surface of the other line.

However your `DistanceFromPoint` returns an unsigned distance: it's always zero or positive. You then use a single perpendicular per line to multiply that by. So you should end up going the wrong way 50% of the time because your distance has no sign.

You might prefer to rearrange, not least because it'll save some of your square roots:

1. get the two axes;
2. for each line, project the vector from any point on the line to each endpoint of the other line onto that line's axis. This produces a signed result;
3. pick the shortest of those results by magnitude;
4. calculate the separation axis as the negative of the shortest number times the axis it was calculated on.

... because if you're embedded by `n` units along axis `q` then the way to resolve that is to move `-n` units along `q`; so pick the least `n`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 2. The only available points I really have are the endpoints on each line. Do I need to calculate a 3rd point?

Comment: No, just use either endpoint. Whichever you prefer. You should get exactly the same answer regardless.

Comment: I'm misunderstanding something or doing something completely wrong but now i get (0,0) always https://ideone.com/J4QQ7y

Comment: The vector may not be perpendicular in some cases.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I don't agree. It feels like it could happen when the intersection point is near the edge of the Minkowski sum but taking the diagonal to a corner will always be further than following the normal to one of the edges. Can you provide either some reasoning or an example?